# How to replace my nodes in my xml, from a inputTextField?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have a inputTextField, and in my inputTextField in my GamePage class i want to be able to take the text that you should be able to write in the inputTextField, and replace the text from the inputTextField with my nodes in my xml-fil. In my Xml class above I want to have that code that converts the text from the inputTextField, ex. If i write "monkey" in my inputTextField, I want to replace {ANIMAL} node in my xml-fil with monkey.

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
    import flash.xml.XMLNode;

    public class Xml extends Sprite 
    {

        private var xmlText:TextField;
        private var xml:XML;
        private var textBox:TextField;

        public function Xml() 
        {

            var xmlString:URLRequest = new URLRequest("tales.xml");
            var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(xmlString);

            xmlLoader.addEventListener("complete", init);

            function init(event:Event):void 
            {

                var xml:XML = XML(xmlLoader.data);
                var xmlText:TextField = new TextField();

                addChild(xmlText);

                xmlText.width = 500; xmlText.height = 500; xmlText.x = 5; xmlText.y = 100;
                xmlText.text = xml.tale; XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;

                var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                format.color = 0x990000;
                format.size = 18;

                xmlText.setTextFormat(format); 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This is my xml-fil ([Google Translated from Swedish](http://translate.google.com/#auto%7Cen%7CDet%20var%20en%20g%C3%A5ng%20en%20%7BDJUR%7D,%20som%20kom%20fr%C3%A5n%20%7BSTAD%7D.%20%7BDJUR%7D%20bodde%20i%20ett%20litet%20litet%20r%C3%B6tt%20julhus,%20precis%20som%20tomten%20g%C3%B6r.%20%7BSTAD%7D%20hade%20ocks%C3%A5%20sin%20jultomte,%20och%20han%20hette%20%7BNAMN%7D.%20%7BDJUR%7D%20och%20%7BNAMN%7D%20var%20n%C3%A4mligen%20b%C3%A4sta%20kompisar%20sen%20j%C3%A4ttel%C3%A4nge,%20och%20de%20bodde%20i%20samma%20lilla%20r%C3%B6da%20hus.%20)):

There was once a {ANIMAL} who came from {CITY}. {ANIMAL} lived in a small little red julhus, just like Santa does. {CITY} also had her Santa Claus, and his name {NAME}. {ANIMAL} and {NAME} was in fact best friends for ages ago, and they lived in the same little red house.

Comment: Try to post your questions in English and be as specific as possible. And also try to format your code and make in the future. Besides that, what is the content of your XML?

Comment: My question is in English, and I just wanna replace my xml {nodes} ... Yes, Im gonna format my code in the future.

Comment: Ah my bad, maybe it's more clear if you type a little more info in the body of your text (now only the title explains the question). I didn't notice the text was your XML tale.

Comment: Oke, now I'm not following anymore. I thought you wanted to replace your text with some of your XML nodes. Try to update your question and be as specific as possible, please write down exactly what you want to achieve. Where should the {CITY}, {NAME} and {ANIMAL} replacements come from?

Comment: Ok, I have a inputTextField, and in my inputTextField in my GamePage class i want to be able to take the text that you should be able to write in the inputTextField, and replace the text from the inputTextField with my nodes in my xml-fil. In my Xml class above I want to have that code that converts the text from the inputTextField, ex. If i write "monkey" in my inputTextField, I want to replace {ANIMAL} node in my xml-fil with monkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the text by the change of an `InputField` you should listen to the `Event.CHANGE` of the `InputFields`. Within this listener you can redirect to a method which will do the replacement. After loading the XML you should also call this method so the initial values are stripped out.

I didn't see the InputFields in your code example so here's a quick example of how you could set it up.

```
private var animalInputField:TextField;
private var cityInputField:TextField;
private var nameInputField:TextField;
private var xmlText:TextField;  

public function Xml() 
{

    var xmlString:URLRequest = new URLRequest("tales.xml");
    var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(xmlString);

    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, init);

    function init(event:Event):void 
    {

        xml = XML(xmlLoader.data);
        xmlText = new TextField();

        addChild(xmlText);

        xmlText.width = 500; xmlText.height = 500; xmlText.x = 5; xmlText.y = 100;
        xmlText.text = xml.tale; 
        XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;

        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        format.color = 0x990000;
        format.size = 18;

        xmlText.setTextFormat(format); 

        // create inputfields
        animalInputField = createInputField();
        cityInputField = createInputField();
        nameInputField = createInputField();

        cityInputField.x = 100;
        nameInputField.x = 200;

        updateTale();
    }
}

private function createInputField() : TextField
{
    var inputField:TextField = TextField(addChild(new TextField()));
    inputField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    inputField.text = '...';

    inputField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onInputChanged);

    return inputField;
}

private function onInputChanged(e:Event):void
{
    updateTale();
}

private function updateTale() : void
{

    var tale:String = xml.tale;

    tale = tale.replace(/{ANIMAL}/g, animalInputField.text);
    tale = tale.replace(/{CITY}/g, cityInputField.text);
    tale = tale.replace(/{NAME}/g, nameInputField.text);

    xmlText.text = tale;
}
```

Within the `updateTale()` method I'm using a regular expression where I use the *'g' (global)* flag to make Flash search to any instance instead of only the first occurrence.

*Please note that in your example you have a private var `xmlText` and `xml` but never use them because within your `init(event:Event)` listener you create two local vars called `xmlText` and `xml` aswell.*

Comment: Thanks, rvmook!!! I should have wrote my tale in English, sorry my bad. Im gonna try your code exampel ...

Comment: Your code dident work. What happend is that on the first line of my xml-fil,{DJUR} and {STAD} disappeared, and thats the only thing that happend ...

Comment: Could you place the contents of your xml?

Comment: Hmmmm I dont really understand your question. Do you mean if I can display my xml content? Yes, I can.

Comment: You are loading an xml, how is it structured? So I can adjust my code accordingly

Comment: Ok, this is my xml-fil: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TALES>
 <tale>Det var en gång en {DJUR}, som kom från {STAD}. 
{DJUR} bodde i ett litet litet rött julhus, precis som tomten gör.
{STAD} hade också sin jultomte, och han hette {NAMN}.
{DJUR} och {NAMN} var nämligen bästa kompisar sen jättelänge, 
och de bodde i samma lilla röda hus.</tale>
</TALES>